# mySQL sum by value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to using SQL and have the following table:

TableA

```
id|fk|value
-----------
1 |1 |100  
2 |1 |200  
3 |2 |300  
4 |2 |400
```

I'm trying to, in another table, display the following:

TableB

```
id|sum
------
1 |300  
2 |700
```

Where row `i` in `TableB` corresponds to the sum of all `fk = i` in `TableA`.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: are you trying to make Table B an actual table or just a result of a query

Comment: I'm trying to make Table B an actual table--NOT a query result

Answer (score 6):

I assume TableB is just query result, not SQL table. Then you need a query like

```
select fk, sum(value)
from tableA
group by fk
```

If you want to create separate table, then you may just do

```
create table TableB as SELECT_ABOVE
```

You don't need to specify columns for new table, since they will be taken from `select`

Comment: Because of the GROUP BY the aggregate function SUM only sums over every group.

Comment: I'm actually trying to make a separate table to show the sum results, not do a query result

Answer (score 0):

```
  create tableB(fk int, sum int)
  select fk, sum(value) 
  into #tableB 
  from 
  tableA 
  group by fk
```

- this shows:
- TableB
- id|sum
- 1 |300
- 2 |700